# android checkbox style not working on ICS

Tags: android, xml, themes

My checkbox styles are being applied on android v5+, but not on v4.x

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/ui_text</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AppDlg</item>
<item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonStyle</item>
<item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxStyle</item>
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="RadioButtonStyle" parent="CheckBoxStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ui_text</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/radiobutton</item>
</style>

<style name="CheckBoxStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ui_text</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dip</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">12dip</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/checkbox</item>
    <item name="android:buttonTint">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/checkbox_size</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/checkbox_size</item>
</style>
...
```

I am compiling against, and targeting SDK 25, with a minimum SDK of 15. I am using support-v4:25.3.0, appcompat-v7:25.3.0, design:25.3.0

Android Studio gives me an error in styles.xml about buttonTint requiring a minimum API level of 21, but even with this line removed I get the same behavior (checkboxes being styled on 5.x, but not on 4.x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I needed to add the following lines to styles.xml

```
<item name="checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxStyle</item>
<item name="radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonStyle</item>
```

to compliment the lines that were already there...

```
<item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/RadioButtonStyle</item>
<item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxStyle</item>
```

!